# API Json Response size limit

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, iis-express

I have an endpoint where it returns the list of students in a college. When I hit that endpoint, it is giving **Response Too Large** message.

I know that there is a size limit for post body data and i.e ~29 MB.
Is there any size limit for a response?

Comment: I am running in the local machine.

Comment: On IIS? Kestrel? Something else?

Comment: Rather than asking 'is there a size limit', you should probably implement paging in your responses.

Comment: VS Studi internal server

Comment: @JessedeWit, I have already implemented pagination where I can fetch records based on a parameter but if I want to retrieve all records, it is throwing an error.

Comment: `VS Studi internal server` So IIS Express?

Comment: @mjwills Yes, you are correct.

Comment: `Response Too Large` is the **exact** and **complete** message? What http status code is it?

Comment: @BalanjaneyuluK That would be an indication that returning all records at once is undesirable. I would recommend to create a default page size and a max page size suitable for your domain. Clients could then loop through the pages to fetch all records.